# JavaFX : StackPane Sequential Transition

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to switch between 3 different `AnchorPane` (on click of a `Button`) with a `FadeTransition` and below is my code,

```
public class TestSlide extends Application {
    private ObjectBinding<Node> frontNode;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        AnchorPane pane1 = new AnchorPane(new Button("1"));
        AnchorPane pane2 = new AnchorPane(new Button("2"));
        AnchorPane pane3 = new AnchorPane(new Button("3"));
        root.getChildren().addAll(pane1, pane2, pane3);

        handleAnimation(root);

        BorderPane border= new BorderPane(root);

        HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
        Button front1 = new Button("Pane 1");
        Button front2 = new Button("Pane 2");
        Button front3 = new Button("Pane 3");
        front1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            pane1.toFront();
        });
        front2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            pane2.toFront();
        });
        front3.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            pane3.toFront();
        });
        bottom.getChildren().addAll(front1, front2, front3);
        border.setBottom(bottom);

        Scene scene = new Scene(border,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void handleAnimation(StackPane root) {
        frontNode = Bindings.valueAt(root.getChildren(),
                Bindings.size(root.getChildren()).subtract(1));
        frontNode.addListener((obs, oldNode, newNode) -> {
            SequentialTransition fadeOutIn = new SequentialTransition();
            if (oldNode != null) {
                FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), oldNode);
                fadeOut.setToValue(0);
                fadeOutIn.getChildren().add(fadeOut);
            }
            if (newNode != null) {
                FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), newNode);
                fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
                fadeIn.setToValue(1);
                fadeOutIn.getChildren().add(fadeIn);
            }
            fadeOutIn.play();
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The `handleAnimation` method is referenced from another SO post.

The problem is ,

1. After launching the application, Click on **Pane 1** `Button`. -> Transition will first show `pane2` and then `pane1`.
2. Now Click on **Pane 3** `Button` -> Transition will first show `pane2` and then `pane3`.
3. Now Click on **Pane 2** `Button` -> Transition will show `pane2` and the problem mentioned in above 2 points doesn't appear again.

Why the transition shows `pane2` before showing the actual pane in points 1 & 2 ? is it due to opacity setting ?

and why after point 3 the problem gets resolved ?

How can i make the transition work to `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` the respective `Pane` without showing the third Pane ?

Comment: I haven't done this but I would guess you can keep track of the front node. When a button is clicked, run a fade-out transition on that node. Use the transition's onfinished to start the fade in on the new front node. Make sure you replace the old front with the node being faded in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the initial state of the children of the `StackPane` is wrong: All nodes have opacity 1. Your desired state when no animation is running has all the nodes but the last one fully transparent (opacity = 0) and the last one fully opaque (opacity = 1). You should be able to fix the issue by initializing the opacities properly:

```
root.getChildren().addAll(pane1, pane2, pane3);

// set opacity for all but the last child to 0
List<Node> children = root.getChildren();
for (int i = children.size()-2; i >= 0; i--) {
    children.get(i).setOpacity(0);
}
```

Otherwise the following happens:

Just after `pane1.toFront()`. Note that (`SequentialTransition` makes sure that the state for the start of the animation is established.

The topmost node is the last child in the list and `----...` is put next to the visible "layer".

```
Pane 1: opacity = 0
Pane 3: opacity = 1 ------------------------------
Pane 2: opacity = 1
```

Now after the first half of the `SequentialTransition` is done, this looks as follows:

```
Pane 1: opacity = 0
Pane 3: opacity = 0
Pane 2: opacity = 1 ------------------------------
```

And after the animation is completeled:

```
Pane 1: opacity = 1 ------------------------------
Pane 3: opacity = 0
Pane 2: opacity = 1
```

Using `pane3.toFront()` produces similar results:

```
Pane 3: opacity = 0
Pane 1: opacity = 1 ------------------------------
Pane 2: opacity = 1
```

```
Pane 3: opacity = 0
Pane 1: opacity = 0
Pane 2: opacity = 1 ------------------------------
```

```
Pane 3: opacity = 1 ------------------------------
Pane 1: opacity = 0
Pane 2: opacity = 1
```